# how to call Square App on IOS using their code?

Tags: ios, ipad, web-applications, safari, square

Sorry but newbie is here. And, I may have not googled hard enough but as I went on searching no one has asked this newbie question yet. I'm really confused how to call Square App.

In this document: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/pos/setup-web#step-1-install-the-square-point-of-sale-app

At the part that say "Initiate a mobile web transaction: iOS"
They tell me to put this line below in a URL format

```
square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data={REPLACE ME}
```

But do not say where and what is REPLACE ME suppose to be.
Can some one kindly enough to help me understand this please?

Comment: An example script that builds the data parameter is shown in the code block immediately below the URL you have referenced

Comment: Thank you. I see it. But I don't understand if I need to put the script below in plain JavaScript file or it has to be in the button function to call. And once read further down, they mention if have not had a js file yet, I should create a new one named it callback.js. So should I have two js or one js file.

Comment: That script needs to execute in response to your "pay" button.  The callback script will be invoked by the Square service once they have processed the transaction

Comment: Thank you, @paulw11. I have figured that out. But your comment still should be the answer for my question here. Im curious if I can make a comment to be a correct answer for the topic? ... hmm will have to figure that out.